# I'm using bootstrap v4 and my bootstrap-select jquery library isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap v4 and my bootstrap-select jquery library isn't working.

This is my code :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

And this my script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    style: 'btn-info',
    size: 4
  });
});
```

And these are my cdns :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the [bootstrap-select library.](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: What mean `isn't work` ? Do you have errors ?

Comment: I think you should add link to jquery.js, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js

Comment: i added  jquery and bootstrap to my project too

Comment: Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/mfrup5bL/56/

Comment: i think it dosent work becuase im using bootstrap v4

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is not currently supported: see issue [#1135](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1135) on GitHub for more info.